I have a list with a grouped by date view but when i sort it, - so it shows the newest date on top (descending) - it works fine until I save the view
After I save the view it changes back to ascending order and I have to manually change it again. I tried saving it into ascending order to see if it might be a bug which just reverts the setting on change but it will just stay in ascending order.

Can you replicate the same behaviour on another list? Is it the same for a public and personal view?
Are you doing it manually or programmatically?  Is the order the only setting you are changing in the view?
What if you create a totally new view?

On another list, which works almost similar, everything works as it should. It's the same with public and personal view. And I tried both manually and programmatically. And yes it's the only thing I changed and didn't work either with a totally new view.
Probably I'm just going to create a new list and hope that it works fine then.
